# What is profile in accept heading of wiki api request

Tags: header, wikidata, wikidata-api

For example, when you perform an call from [summary api](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Page%20content/get_page_summary__title_) of wikipedia, there is this header in the request

```
accept:application/json; charset=utf-8; profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/Summary/1.3.7"
```

What is the purpose of this particular bit. I would like to understand since the value changes when you, for example, use the VisualEditor or access the api with different mean.
`profile="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/Summary/1.3.7"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specifies the response format and provides convenient access to a human-readable documentation.

The URL in your header leads to nowhere, but https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Specs/Summary/1.3.0 does exist and is probably valid for 1.3.7 as well.